# Why I can't see the array of protocol on javascript WebSocket?

Tags: javascript

As you can see, sec-WebSocket-Protocol display "a, b" as string, but from the WebSocket Object, there is only 'a'; why?

[image]

Comment: *"As you can see, sec-WebSocket-Protocal display "a, b" as string, but from the WebSocket Object, there is only 'a'; why?"* No idea we can only get a idea downloading the source code of the browser and check it.. a educated guess would  be simply a bug or does not support multiple protocols in the javascript API.

Answer (score 2):

> The `WebSocket.protocol` read-only property returns the name of the sub-protocol the server selected; this will be one of the strings specified in the protocols parameter when creating the WebSocket object.

~ [MDN, WebSocket.protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/protocol)

Comment: my question is why WebSocket.protocal display different from sec-WebSocket-Protocol from the header

Comment: Because server has to select only one protocol from ```a, b```